# Cannot install PHP APC on Windows, Apache

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, php, dll

i cant seem to install PHP APC on my windows 7 x64, apache, php 5.3.2 x86 VC9. have downloaded the approperiate file from http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

added to my php.ini

```
[PHP_APC]
extension=php_apc.dll

[APC]
apc.enabled = 1
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 64
apc.max_file_size = 10M
apc.stat=1
```

as i learnt from http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=63&p=24098#p24098

still failed with

[image: https://farm5.static.flickr.com/4100/4826248909_fe66b0a3cc.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally managed to install apc with the help from [here](http://www.rawseo.com/news/2009/06/09/how-to-install-alternative-php-cache/). i installed on IIS7

added to end of `php.ini`

```
[PHP_APC]
extension=php_apc.dll

apc.shm_segments=1
apc.optimization=0
apc.shm_size=128
apc.ttl=7200
apc.user_ttl=7200
apc.num_files_hint=1024
apc.mmap_file_mask=/tmp/apc.XXXXXX
apc.enable_cli=1
```

tho i got no idea what the configuration does